# redirect в Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему с перенаправлениями.

Есть файл `htaccess`.

Необходимо в нем реализовать перенаправления со страницы:

`www.site.by/about/` на страницу `www.site.by/ru/o-kompanii/`

Пробовал вставлять конструкцию:

```
Redirect 301 /about/  http://www.site.by/ru/o-kompanii/
RewriteRule ^/about/$ http://www.site.by/ru/o-kompanii/ [R=301;L]
```

Не работают.

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.%1/$1" [L,R=301]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
        RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
        RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/*$ - [L]
        RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: "Redirect 301 /about/ http://www.site.by/ru/o-kompanii/" Этот вариант отработал у меня отлично. Попробуйте разместить его после  RewriteBase /

Comment: Вот каков итог: перенаправляет сюда >>> http://www.site.by/ru/o-kompanii/?q=about/

Comment: Ведь это и требовалось или нет?

Comment: нет, нужно просто http://www.site.by/ru/o-kompanii/

Comment: я так понимаю, конструкция  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA] добавляет данный параметр

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Для начала пройдемся по ошибкам в коде:

```
RewriteRule ^/about/$ http://www.site.by/ru/o-kompanii/ [R=301;L]
```

Во-первых, флаги указываются через запятую.
Во-вторых, при использовании `RewriteRule` в левой части выражения первый `/` опускается.

Вот так будет выглядеть полный .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Благодаря флагу L нижеследующие правила для этого URL не будут работать.
# Иными словами это конечный редирект.
RewriteRule ^about/$ /ru/o-kompanii/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.%1/$1" [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/*$ - [L]

RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: к сожалению, вообще никакого перенаправления, с использованием данной конструкции

Comment: @ДмитрийКамеш , я немного изменил .htaccess. В таком виде он точно должен работать. Проверить можно тут: `http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/`.